# Error with starting activity from fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragmentactivity

So, I've been working on a social media.
When from the "profile viewer" the user wants to edit his profile I want to start another activity, but it's like that the button can't find the function that starts the activity.
Sorry for my poor English.
I hope you understood

Here is the code:

```java
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {
    private FirebaseUser user;
    private DatabaseReference reference;

    private String userid;

    @Nullable
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull @NotNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        userid = user.getUid();

        reference.child(userid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                User userProfile = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

                if (userProfile != null) {
                    String username = userProfile.username;
                    String description = userProfile.desc;
                    Integer followers = userProfile.followers;
                    Integer following = userProfile.following;
                    String displayname = userProfile.displayname;
                    Boolean verified = userProfile.verified;
                    TextView usernametxt = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView17);
                    TextView descriptiontxt = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView19);
                    TextView followerstxt = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView22);
                    TextView followingtxt = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView26);
                    TextView displaynametxt = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView28);

                    usernametxt.setText(username);
                    descriptiontxt.setText(description);
                    followerstxt.setText(followers.toString());
                    followingtxt.setText(following.toString());
                    displaynametxt.setText(displayname);

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Failed to load profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        });

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
    }

    public void editprofile(View view) {
        Intent pog = new Intent(getContext(), editprofile.class);
        startActivity(pog);
    }
}
```

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView22"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:text="Loading..."
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.885"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.087" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView21"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
    android:text="Followers:"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.687"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.087" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView20"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
    android:text="Bio:"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.08"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.157" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView24"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
    android:text="Following:"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.686"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.127" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
    android:text="Your profile"
    android:textSize="34sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.023" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView17"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:text="Loading..."
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.337"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.099" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView28"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:text="Loading..."
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.382"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.053" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView26"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:text="Loading..."
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.883"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.127" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView19"
    android:layout_width="206dp"
    android:layout_height="109dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:hint="no bio yet"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.078"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.213" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView15"
    android:layout_width="92dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.041"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.069"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_account_circle_24" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="161dp"
    android:layout_height="47dp"
    android:background="#02f760"
    android:text="Edit profile"
    android:onClick="editprofile"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.47"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.396" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Here is the error:
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.nordicalhavera.kitchub, PID: 10525
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method editprofile(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton with id 'button'
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:447)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:405)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

Comment: Please add the error

Comment: yeah, sure https://pastebin.com/dr1hBxi5

Comment: above layout is for mainActivity or for  your fragment? if it is for activity ,editprofile method should be in activity .

Comment: i may misunderstood the question, but the layout above is for the fragment

Comment: Can you add this **android:clickable="true"** below this **android:onClick="editprofile"** and try?

Comment: still crashes:( as i see the error is that it can't find the function. bottom navigation activities are very strange.i have never got a problem with that in a "normal activity"

Comment: as i see, the problem is that it can't find the function even tho it is in there. i have tried both the onclicklistnener and the function, both none of them works:(